# How to call numpad using action button not from text field

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

I know this is silly question but as a beginner at xcode, and i can't find the answer from any source, can i call numpad (numberic keyboard) from my action button? I just want my action button can call numpad like text field do. what code should i insert in my action button?

my code:

```
- (IBAction)setLoopBtn:(id)sender
{

}
```

Thank you again for sharing your knowledge to noob like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(IBAction) ButtonClick
{
      txtField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
     [txtField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `UITextField` with a frame that puts it off the visible screen.  Assign the type of keyboard you want to display as the default for that field.  When the button is tapped, send `becomeFirstResponder` to your off-screen field.

Comment: after i read your post and implement it using Brijesh code, my numpad is show now! thank you both of you! but how i hide it now? thank you anyway

Comment: Look in the documentation for things called `resignFirstResponder` and `endEditing`.